# I am getting a Type error on clicking the button stating that function is not dfined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, typeerror, eventhandler

I am getting a `Type error` on clicking the button stating that function is not defined.

When I run the front end server and click the "ADD" button, the browser shows that function `putToDB` is not defined.

```
putToDb = (message) => {
   console.log("rahul");
   let currentIds = this.state.data.map((data)=>data.id);
   let idToBeAdded = 0;
   while(currentIds.includes(idToBeAdded)){
       ++idToBeAdded;
   }

   axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/putData',{
       id:idToBeAdded,
      message:message,
  })
};
```

In render Section

```
<div style={{ padding: '50px' }}>
<input type="text"
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}
  placeholder="add something in the database"
  style={{ width: '200px' }}
/>
<button onClick={() => this.putToDB(this.state.message)}>
   ADD
</button>enter code here
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your entire component code. It's not clear what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

it is because the 'b' in 'putToDb' is lowercase while you are calling trying to call a function with a uppercase 'b' at the end.

In the future please upload you entire component structure and format your code.